# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘knitr’

Tags: r

I am trying to read my read my cvs data using the below command

```
ABCT2023 <- read.csv(file = "TPAC ABCT 2023 Data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

when I run this command, I receive the following error
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘knitr’

I have tried to download knitr in order to fix this but it does not allow me to. It just gives the error again.
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘knitr’

Comment: Are you using Rstudio or another IDE, or just base R?

Comment: what happens if you run `install.packages("knitr")`?

Comment: Are you typing this directly into the R console? Are you are creating an RMarkdown document? `read.csv` shouldn't have anything to do with `knitr`. It is very odd that you could be getting that particular error for that line. But if you are trying to compile an RMarkdown document, then it really doesn't matter what R code you try to run in the document, you need `knitr` just to view the output of the RMarkdown file.

Answer (score 0):

That may be caused by a failed installation of the `knitr` package.

You can try starting a new R session, install `knitr` successfully ( i.e. `install.packages("knitr")` ), and then run that line of code to read your data.

Comment: But why would a call to `read.csv` require `knitr`? Those should be completely unrelated.